# Disable temporarily vue.js auto re-rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, backtracking

I have a 2d array in JavaScript, and I have to do a backtracking algorithm on it. I noticed that if I remove the Vue instance from my app, the algorithm takes only about 20 milliseconds. With Vue which tries to re-render on every iteration, it takes 150 ms.
There is a way to temporarily disable Vue re-rendering in order to make my algorithm faster?

This is my actual code:

```
var myArray = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myArray[i] = new Array(10);
}

/* Populate the array with some data */

var app = new Vue({
    data: {
        array: myArray
    }
});

backTrack();

function backTrack() {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Why would your algorithm trigger the render ?

Comment: Because the algorithm edits the array multiple times, so I think that Vue tries to rendering again and again while I'm doing that.

Comment: You should not make your algorithm work on the data linked to the component. Try to run it on a temporary array while processing, then put that array in the component data.

Comment: Probably best to run the algorithm and then set the return to data. But you could also try using `Object.freeze()` on `{array: [...]}` before running the backtrack. From the docs:

>  ...Object.freeze(), which prevents existing properties from being changed, which also means the reactivity system can’t track changes.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: Yes, I've tried as suggested by Seblor to make a temporary copy of the array and then update the component data array and it works. Thanks for the advice.

fstep I don't want to loose the ability to track changes; I want it only temporarly.